# Sifr displaying twice - IE only?

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer, sifr, sifr3

A client is saying that this page is displaying the sifr titles twice. Anybody had this? It doesn't happen all the time which is even more peculiar.

Here is one of the pages:
http://www.frontier-economics.com/europe/en/news/906/

Is it just IE? Any thoughts hugely appreciated!!

Comment: Here is what they sent to me:
http://www.burnt.net/clients/frontier/sifr.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it matters, as there's no reason for you to be using sIFR on that page (or any other), because:

1. Georgia, Helvetica (and the similar Arial), & Verdana are all [very commonly installed fonts](http://www.visibone.com/font/FontResults.html).
2. Georgia, Arial, & Verdana are also part of [Microsoft's core fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web), which can be freely distributed.
3. sIFR is now completely deprecated by native [browser support of dynamic web fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Web_Typography%29).**[*](http://reisio.com/examples/webfonts/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Unfortunately the fonts I'm using the sifr for are Helvetica Neue Light and Garamond, so it, or something similar, is required.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, but do notice that while the page is loading there appears to be for a split second two instances (which then finishes as one).

You could avoid it either way by setting a height on the element to match its line-height, and adding overflow: hidden;.

You could also try a different snapshot of sIFR3, or sIFR2, or using a modern web font implementation as already suggested.

If you worry about accidental redistribution of commercial fonts, it would be well worth the time to find similar-looking free alternatives, which abound.